# Finding interval of definition without initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on a problem that wished for a solution to be verified and given a interval of definition.

$$y'=1+y^2$$
$$y=\tan(x+c)$$

Verifying this is a cinch as $\sec^2(x) = 1+\tan^2(x)$. However, since $\tan(x)$ has an infinite number of intervals on which it is defined, $(n\pi/2, (n+1)\pi/2)$, I don't know how to give an interval of definition. All problems I had worked with before had given an initial value which allowed me to select an interval by simply seeing where the initial value was.

I was given the answer $-\pi/2 < x+c < \pi/2$ which seems to be the interval containing the origin. Why was this specific interval selected? I have also read from other questions on the topic that every interval is a different solution.

I apologize in advance for not knowing how to use LaTeX.

Comment: thank you kind stranger for the edit

Comment: You're welcome... Christophermark Lee +1

Comment: That $\tan(x)$ has an infinite number of intervals on which it is defined in $(n\pi/2, (n+1)\pi/2)$ is wrong. Should be  $(n\pi-\pi/2, n\pi+\pi/2)$.

Comment: You can't technically decide on the interval of definition without knowing where the initial point was supposed to be. It will be the particular interval where $\tan$ is defined that contains the initial point. (Of course the whole thing is autonomous, so the actual trajectory looks the same regardless of when you start it up.)

Answer (score 0):

If no initial condition, or no other information to determine the interval was given, then it sounds like this was just a poorly made exercise, wherever you obtained it from, but perhaps it is also supposed to be clear from context what interval you should be working with.